# VB - Searching a text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing VB at school and we are searching a text file. However, if no results are found, I want to output "There are no results" ONCE. I have tried it but it outputs it for every line of code in the text file. How would I do this?

```
Module Module1
Dim townname, findtown, findname, teamname, coachname, phone As String
Dim choice As String
Sub Main()

    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Please pick an option:")
        Console.WriteLine("1. Search team by team name - Press 1")
        Console.WriteLine("2. Search team by town name - Press 2")
        Console.WriteLine("3. End Program - Press 3")

        choice = Console.ReadLine

        Select Case choice


            Case 1
                Console.Write("Enter the team name:")
                findname = Console.ReadLine()
                FileOpen(1, "TeamdataFile.txt", OpenMode.Input)

                Do
                    Input(1, teamname)
                    Input(1, townname)
                    Input(1, coachname)
                    Input(1, phone)

                    If teamname.ToLower = findname.ToLower Then

                        Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}, from {1}, coach: {2}, contact: {3}", teamname, townname, coachname, phone)
                    End If

                Loop Until EOF(1)
                FileClose(1)
                Console.ReadLine()

            Case 2
                Console.Write("Enter the town the team is from:")
                findtown = Console.ReadLine()
                FileOpen(1, "TeamdataFile.txt", OpenMode.Input)

                Do
                    Input(1, teamname)
                    Input(1, townname)
                    Input(1, coachname)
                    Input(1, phone)

                    If townname.ToLower = findtown.ToLower Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}, from {1}, coach: {2}, contact: {3}", teamname, townname, coachname, phone)
                    End If

                Loop Until EOF(1)
                FileClose(1)
                Console.ReadLine()
            Case 3
                End
            Case Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid option - Choose option 1 or 2 or 3")
        End Select
    Loop Until choice = "1" Or choice = "2" Or choice = "3"
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reacting immediately at the found name, just set a boolean variable to true, let the check continue till the end of file or break the loop immediately. After the loop exit print the result based on the boolean value

```
   Dim foundResult As Boolean

   .....
   Select Case choice
        Case 1
            Console.Write("Enter the team name:")
            findname = Console.ReadLine()
            FileOpen(1, "TeamdataFile.txt", OpenMode.Input)
            foundResult = False
            Do
                Input(1, teamname)
                Input(1, townname)
                Input(1, coachname)
                Input(1, phone)

                If teamname.ToLower = findname.ToLower Then
                    foundResult = True
                    Exit While
                End If

            Loop Until EOF(1)
            FileClose(1)
            if foundResult = True Then
                Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}, from {1}, coach: {2}, contact: {3}", teamname, townname, coachname, phone)
            else
                Console.WriteLine("There are no results"
            End if
      ......
```

As a side note, you really should stop to use the old fashioned FileOpen, Input, FileClose. These functions are here just for compatibility with VB6. The NET Framework has better methods for File handling. You should use the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and its methods that are specifically designed for NET. All of the System.IO namespace is an order of magnitude more powerful.